# Data structure for simulated world game

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

This is about an open world game in java where millions of units (special ships) are going to move from one planet to another.
I want to make any ship customizable by using and compounding it out of basic modules, the problem is I don't know how to represent all that information in an efficient way, but what I think is:

- use an array of objects (one obj per ship) - but that doesn't seem to work.
- make a few predefined types of ships, and represent the number of ships in a fleet with an int, but that would mean throwing away the whole idea of customizing the ships, uhm.

How could I resolve this?

Comment: `to use array of objects (one obj per ship) - but that doesnt seems to work.` , whats the problem with this ? , and why not go for more sophisticated datastructures like ArrayList

Comment: Create a base ship and extend it to make other ships.  Keep your ships in a List<Base>.

Comment: Find a way that works for 100 ships - plenty of time to make it work for 1 million when it will be needed. ArrayList are a fine structure to start (in memory). You'll probably want to store them at some point too, but "millions of units" is nothing frightening for any kind of datastore.

Comment: If you want to `implement if from basic modules`, you can have a parent class `ship` which has all the basic features and then create child classes for different types fo ships which have different features but same basic features. Essentially, you use inheritance

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth reading up on some design patterns, particularly the [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). Some quick ideas off the top of my head would be to have one instance of each "base" ship and one instance of each of the parts that can be added. Then you can access these shared instances in each other ship. Things like ammo and health can be unique to each ship as they are simple numbers and won't take up nearly as much memory. It may take some thinking but I feel Flyweight is your best starting point. Good luck!